# Declaring an Iterator

Tags: java, iterator, iteration

I am having trouble with the syntax on an iterator I created. I would use a for-each loop, except I need to edit the elements that I would be pulling out of that loop. I created a class called Players which creates a List of 4 Hands(Hand is another class that represents an individual player) in a card game. I am trying to create an iterator for this class, which is giving me trouble. My implementation is as follows:

```
public class Players
{ ....
    public class PlayerIterator implements Iterator<Hand>
    {
        private final Iterator<Hand> iterator;
        private PlayerIterator()
        {
            this.iterator = players.iterator();
        }
        ....
     }
 }
```

As far as I know, my implementation seems correct, based on the fact that I havent received any errors in eclipse. I am, however, having trouble declaring an iterator in the actual program. How would I declare an iterator like that?

Right now this is giving me an error:

```
Iterator<Hand> it = Players.PlayerIterator();
```

- Hand: The class of variables I am iterating through: a list of 4 Hands
- Players: The class that constructs the list of Hands and contains the iterator implementation
- PlayerIterator: The class within the Players class that implements the iterator

Does this make sense? I have a very loose grasp on iterators, so if I have not provided enough information I could easily create more.

Comment: "Right now this is giving me an error" --> What's the error? We cannot read your mind.

Comment: This isn't a loose grasp of `Iterator`, it is a loose grasp of nested classes in Java. Read [a tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html).

Comment: @user3580294 sorry, its saying the method "PlayerIterator" is undefined for the "Players" class. It thinks I am calling a method when really Im trying to declare the iterator

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit difficult to tell from the code you have posted, but I think you might just be missing a `new` keyword. I assume you have something like the following outside of the Players class:

```
Players players = new Players();
```

where an instance of the Players class has some collection of Hands as one of its fields. In this case what you want to do is this:

```
Iterator<Hand> iterator = players.new PlayerIterator();
```

However, it also looks like you might have intended `PlayerIterator` to be a static class, which would be needed if the Players class has a *static* collection of Hands:

```
private static List<Hand> players = new ArrayList<Hand>();
```

Then you want to do this:

```
Iterator<Hand> iterator = new Players.PlayerIterator();
```

If you could post more of your code, it would be easier to guide you to the right solution. Another option might be to make `Players` implement [`Iterable<Hand>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html), which means you can directly loop over a Players instance in a for-each loop.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the point of creating a `Hand` iterator when your already have a list of `Hand`s in your class. It's hard to understand what your code is trying to do, but if I understand your scenario correctly, the following should suffice:

```
public class Players implements Iterable<Hand> {
    List<Hand> hands = ...

    //...

    @Override
    public Iterator<Hand> iterator() {
        return hands.iterator();
    }

    //...
}
```